# OSGeo4W (gdal 2.1.0) and gdal2tiles

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w, gdal2tiles

I've tried the x86 and x64 versions of OSGeo4W, but gdal2tiles is missing.

Has gdal2tiles been removed from OSGeo4W?

```
               -={ OSGeo4W Shell Commands }=-

   bmp2tiff            msencrypt           scalebar
   cs2cs               nad2bin             shp2img
   curl                nccopy              shptree
   dllupdate           ncdump              shptreetst
   fax2ps              ncgen               shptreevis
   fax2tiff            ncgen3              sortshp
   gdaladdo            nearblack           testepsg
   gdalbuildvrt        nircmd              textreplace
   gdaldem             nircmdc             thumbnail
   gdalenhance         ogdi_import         tiff2bw
   gdalinfo            ogdi_info           tiff2pdf
   gdallocationinfo    ogr2ogr             tiff2ps
   gdalmanage          ogrinfo             tiff2rgba
   gdalserver          ogrlineref          tiffcmp
   gdalsrsinfo         ogrtindex           tiffcp
   gdaltindex          opj_compress        tiffcrop
   gdaltransform       opj_decompress      tiffdither
   gdalwarp            opj_dump            tiffdump
   gdal_contour        osgeo4w-setup       tiffinfo
   gdal_grid           pal2rgb             tiffmedian
   gdal_rasterize      portmap             tiffset
   gdal_translate      ppm2tiff            tiffsplit
   geod                proj                tile4ms
   geotifcp            psql                vcredist_2013_x86
   gif2tiff            ras2tiff            xmlcatalog
   gltpd               raw2tiff            xmllint
   legend              rgb2ycbcr           xxmklink
   listgeo             rpcgen
   mapserv             rpcinfo


   apache-install     o-help             setup
   apache-restart     o4w_env
   apache-uninstall   setup-test
```

GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25

Answer (score 4):

I was using the wrong options in the OSGeo4W installer.

If going down the "Express Desktop Install" path, gdal2tiles either comes with the "QGIS", "OpenEV", or "GRASS GIS" option. It's not provided under the "GDAL" option.

Answer (score 0):

It should be there. At least on Linux distributions, the `gdal2tiles` command actually has `.py` at the end of it, I'm guessing to indicate it uses `Python`. If you look here, you can find it along with the other `xxx.py` operations:

https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/gdal/files/

Comment: In the OSGeo4W shell entering just "gdal2tiles" works. It actually runs gdal2tiles.bat which contains command `@python "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdal2tiles.py" %*  `